# Update radio buttons with response in Angular 2

Tags: angular, data-binding, radio-button, angular2-forms

I have two radio buttons with Yes No labels. Now I have to set the value with the response coming from service. The values coming are True and False. I am not able to set them in  html.
Please can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Why can't you set them with html? Set one radio buttons `checked` attribute to whether its true or false.

Comment: I tried using checked attribute. It is getting set but I am not able to change the radio button after that. Can you post any solution

Comment: What do you mean by change it? Are you mapping the response from the service into an object or variable? And then you want to change that variable? Like to post it back to the service later?

Comment: No no i am setting the value from the reponse and  it getting set to No  button. After that when I am trying to select Yes , its not getting selected.

Comment: try by giving [(ngModule)] to both radio button

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute checked in HTML and set its value based on your model in the component. For example,

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {

    public state = false;

    ngOnInit() {

      // get data from your service
       this.service.getData()
         .subscribe(response : boolean=>{
           this.state = response;
         })
    }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
 <input type="radio" name="answer" [value="Yes" [checked]="!state"/> Yes <br>
 <input type="radio" name="answer" value="No" [checked]="state"> No <br>
```

Comment: This would literally crash his application because of [checked]=state (no quote marks), he asked about yes or no button based on a boolean and you provided 3 buttons, only one of the buttons has anything to do with the state. You also included a bunch of code from stackblitz starter template totally unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you set a variable based on the response named `myBool` you can do this:

```
<input type="radio" [checked]="myBool" (click)="myBool = true" />
<input type="radio" [checked]="!myBool" (click)="myBool = false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above response it is coming as Boolean value True or false, If response is coming as 1 & 2 in place of true or false then how you will set this values to input type radio